# How to calculate the Cumprinc in C#?

Tags: c#, excel

I tried to calculate the `Cumprinc` formula from Microsoft Excel like this:

```
for (double i = start; i <= end; i++)
{
    if (type > 0)
    {

        principal += payment - (payment * Math.Pow((1 + rate), (i - 2)) - payment) * rate;

    }
    else
    {
         principal+=payment-(payment*Math.Pow((1+rate),(i-1))-payment)*rate;
    }
}
```

However, it gave a solution different from Ms-excel.

I need the exact logic to calculate the `CUMPRINC` formula.

Comment: principal is the calculation of CUMPRINC

Comment: Try this: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/microsoft.office.interop.excel.iworksheetfunction.cumprinc.aspx

Comment: Check out this .net library [ExcelFinancialFunctions](https://github.com/fsprojects/ExcelFinancialFunctions)

Comment: I can't get the exact logic for this formula so can you share the code to calculate this formula.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It looks like you don't change your principal on each iteration of your loop meaning each months interest will be the same. It's also not clear from your question whether you've adjusted the initial balance to take into account any payments up to the start period.

The basic logic with your approach should be:

- Calculate the remaining balance
- For each period between start and end

  - calculate the principal paid using the remaining balance and add that to the cumulative total
  - Deduct the principal paid from the remaining balance

The easiest way to calculate the principal paid in the month is to take the interest from the month and deduct it from the monthly payment. This means it makes sense to calculate the monthly payment upfront. The formulae for calculating the monthly payment and remaining balance can be found [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mortgage_calculator).

The following method should give the same result as excel (accurate to 10 decimal places based on the example on the [CUMPRINC MS page](https://support.office.com/en-sg/article/CUMPRINC-function-94a4516d-bd65-41a1-bc16-053a6af4c04d); you might want to play around with the types if you need to be more accurate than that).

```
private static decimal CumPrinc(double rate, int periods, decimal pV, int start, int end, int type)
{
    //adjust the start and end periods based on the type
    //if it's 1 then payments are at the beginning of the period
    //which is the same as the end of the previous period
    if (type == 1)
    {
        start -= 1;
        end -= 1;
    }

    //calculate the monthlyPayment
    decimal monthlyPayment = (decimal)((rate * (double)pV * Math.Pow((1 + rate), periods)) / (Math.Pow((1 + rate), periods) - 1));

    //calculate the remaining balance
    decimal remainingBalance = (decimal)((Math.Pow((1 + rate), start - 1) * (double)pV) - (((Math.Pow((1 + rate), start - 1) - 1) / rate) * (double)monthlyPayment));

    decimal principal = 0;
    for (int i = start; i <= end; i++)
    {
        //get the interest for the month
        decimal monthlyInterest = remainingBalance * (decimal)rate;
        //the principal for the month is the payment less the interest
        decimal monthlyPrincipal = monthlyPayment - monthlyInterest;
        //add the months principal to the running total
        principal += monthlyPrincipal;
        //deduct the months principal from the remaining balance
        remainingBalance -= monthlyPrincipal;                
    }

    return principal;
}
```

Once you have a method for calculating the remaining balance for a given period though you could remove the need for looping altogether by calculating the remaining balance at the start of the period and the remaining balance at the end of the period then returning the difference:

```
private static decimal CumPrinc(double rate, int periods, decimal pV, int start, int end, int type)
{
    //adjust the start and end periods based on the type
    //if it's 1 then payments are at the beginning of the period
    //which is the same as the end of the previous period
    if (type == 1)
    {
        start -= 1;
        end -= 1;
    }

    //calculate the monthlyPayment
    decimal monthlyPayment = (decimal)((rate * (double)pV * Math.Pow((1 + rate), periods)) / (Math.Pow((1 + rate), periods) - 1));

    decimal remainingBalanceAtStart = (decimal)((Math.Pow((1 + rate), start - 1) * (double)pV) - (((Math.Pow((1 + rate), start - 1) - 1) / rate) * (double)monthlyPayment));

    decimal remainingBalanceAtEnd = (decimal)((Math.Pow((1 + rate), end) * (double)pV) - (((Math.Pow((1 + rate), end) - 1) / rate) * (double)monthlyPayment));

    return remainingBalanceAtEnd - remainingBalanceAtStart;
}
```